# defining an optional with a default

Tags: parameters, clojure, default, option-type

I'm trying to define a function with optional parameters and each optional also has a default if it is not passed in.
but i cannot get it to compile, and cannot find anything on the web to suggest something that will work.

here is what i have

```
defn test-optional-default-params [manA manB manC & [optA optB optC optD optE]
                                   :or {[optA optAdef
                                        optB optBdef
                                        optC optCdef
                                        optD optDdef
                                        optE optEdef]}]
```

(prn (str "manB->" manB ", mnC->" manC ", optA->" optA ", optB->" optB ", optC->" optC ", optD->" optD ", optE->" optE)))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```
(defn f [a b & {:keys [c d e] :or {c defaultc d defaultd e defaulte}}]
  blabla)
```

But you will have to do

```
(f 1 2 :c 3 :d 4 :e 5)
```

So you can maybe do something like this (I tried with a basic function : addition) :

```
(defn add-rest* [c d e]
  (+ c d e))

(def add-rest*
  (fnil add-rest* 0 0 0))

(defn add
  [a b & [c d e]]
  (+ a b (add-rest c d e)))

(add 1 1) ;; 2
(add 1 1 1) ;; 3
(add 1 1 1 1) ;; 4
```

Comment: is the * mean optional all params?

Comment: I think i prefer the first option of 'f ab {:c c etc}'

Comment: No it is just a 'random' name

Answer (score 1):

You can use multi-arity functions, so example with addition with default values of 0 becomes:

```
(defn f+
  ([a b]        (f+ a b 0 0 0))
  ([a b c]      (f+ a b c 0 0))
  ([a b c d]    (f+ a b c d 0))
  ([a b c d e]  (+ a b c d e)))
```

Replace + above with desired function of five variables.
Usage of the above becomes:

```
(f+ 1 2)         ;; 3
(f+ 1 2 3)       ;; 6
(f+ 1 2 3 4)     ;; 10
(f+ 1 2 3 4 5)   ;; 15
```

[Note: also discussed previously with additional options](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3208347/how-to-create-default-value-for-function-argument-in-clojure)